# How to add string into list(index) depends on the condition of the string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to insert the string in the index of string if there is no ";" in the string.
This is the sample string:-

```
[1234] 1 ABC 123;

[5678] 2 DEF 456; 

[9874] 1 GHI 987

[1234] 1 ABC 123;

[5678] 2 DEF 456; 

[9874] 1 GHI 987
```

I wanted to make it when the string contains ";", it will still in index (0), then when the string does not have ";", for example **[9874] 1 GHI 987**, it will continue to next index(1).. and the loop goes on.

so the output should be like this:

```
[1234] 1 ABC 123; [5678] 2 DEF 456;  [9874] 1 GHI 987

[1234] 1 ABC 123; [5678] 2 DEF 456; [9874] 1 GHI 987
```

What I have tried is

```
        Dim ulist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim olist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim tempp As String = ""

        For i As Integer = 0 To ulist.Count - 1 Step 1
            If i = 0 Then
                tempp = ulist(i).ToString

            ElseIf i = ulist.Count - 1 Then 
                If ulist(i).ToString.Contains(";") Then
                    olist.Add(tempp)
                    tempp = ulist(i).ToString
                    olist.Add(tempp)
                Else
                    tempp = tempp & " " & ulist(i).ToString
                    olist.Add(tempp)
                End If

            Else 
                If ulist(i).ToString.Contains(";") Then
                    olist.Add(tempp)
                    tempp = ulist(i).ToString
                Else
                    tempp = tempp & " " & ulist(i).ToString
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

but then, using the code above, the output shows:

```
[1234] 1 ABC 123; 

[5678] 2 DEF 456;  [9874] 1 GHI 987

[1234] 1 ABC 123; 

[5678] 2 DEF 456; [9874] 1 GHI 987
```

Comment: Try this (I'm writing here, so check the syntax)  `oList.Add("") dim lineCount as Integer = 0 For i As Integer = 0 To ulist.Count - 1 Dim currentLine as string = ulist(i)     If currentLine.Contains(";") Then oList(lineCount) += ChrW(32) & currentLine else oList(lineCount) += chrW(32) & currentLine lineCount += 1 If i < ulist.Count - 1 Then oList.Add("") end If next`

Comment: this only consider 2 string which is ABC & DEF, the GHI doesnt included..@Jimi

Comment: Have you actually tested that code? Are the lines separated by an empty line, maybe? If so, add that check: after `dim currentLine as String = ulist(i)`, add: `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLine) then Continue For`

Comment: yes i tested the code, the GHI still being ignored. it only print `[1234] 1 ABC 123; 

[5678] 2 DEF 456;` the string that contains ";". I added the new line of codes, the result still the same. @Jimi

Comment: See the results here: [DotNet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E1Vout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Dim oIndex As Integer = 0 'index for oList
Dim builder As New StringBuilder() 'used to build a line before inserting into olist

For uIndex = 0 To ulist.Count - 1
    If ulist(uIndex).Contains(";") Then
        'If ; exists, keep building string
        builder.Append(ulist(uIndex)).Append(" ") 
    Else 
        'If ; does not exist, add last entry to string            
        builder.Append(ulist(uIndex))  
        'add string to olist
        olist.Add(builder.ToString)
        'clear string
        builder.Clear()
        'increment olist index (start new line)
        oIndex = oIndex + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much @Anu6is May I ask a question? Why do we need to use string builder in this situation?

Comment: it's not a necessity, I prefer StringBuilder when concatenating strings as it's slightly more efficient (probably doesn't have much of an impact in this case though). You could just have something like `oList(oIndex) += " " & uList(uIndex)`